# Get image src within directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive with an `img` tag inside it.

```
angular.module('example')
     .directive('customDirective', function() {
        return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace: true,
           transclude: true,
           scope: {}, //isolate scope
           templateUrl: 'directives/customDirective.html'
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              // returns undefined
              console.log(element.find('img').src);
           }
        };
     });
```

**the directive template:**

```
<div class="customDirective">
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

I'm trying to get a hold of the `src` attribute on the image tag.

Comment: look in 'attrs' of the IMG element

Comment: Change element.find('img').src to element.find('img')[0].src, find returns a jqLite object too.

Answer (score 0):

var src = element.find('img').attr('src');

This is assuming there is only a single img tag.

Answer (score -2):

It would probably be easier to set the source in your directive.

### Directive

```
angular.module('example')
 .directive('customDirective', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
       transclude: true,
       templateUrl: 'directives/customDirective.html'
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.imgSrc = 'image.jpg';
       }
    };
 });
```

### Template

```
<div class="customDirective">
  <img ng-src="{{imgSrc}}" />
</div>
```

Then your code drives the template instead of you needing to read data out of the template.